# Get the object with the most recent date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have an array of objects of type `Thing`:

```
class Thing: NSObject {
    var data: String
    var type: String
   var created: NSDate
}
```

These things have an NSDate property called `created`.  My aim is to write a function that reads the `created` property of every thing in the array and returns the thing that has the most recent date.  The function looks like this:

```
public func getLastSwipe(list: Array<Thing>) -> Thing {
    return someThing
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `reduce` if you wanted. This will find the object with the highest timestamp.

```
var mostRecent = list.reduce(list[0], { $0.created.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.created.timeIntervalSince1970 ? $0 : $1 } )
```

If your dates are not all in the past, you'll have to also compare against the current date to determine a cutoff. If your dates are all in the future, you'll want to switch the `>` to `<` to find the next future date (lowest timestamp).

Comment: I'll go through the documentation to try to understand what it does and then implement it and see if it works

Comment: `reduce` takes an initial value (`list[0]`) and a block (`{ ... }`). The block is executed on every element in `list`, with `$0` equal to the current (or initial) statement value and `$1` equal to the current list item value. The result of this block is assigned to `$0` on the next iteration and then finally to `mostRecent` when complete.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, does the combine still exist ? I can't find it

Comment: It looks like they've changed the name of the second parameter. If you remove the `combine:` name, it should work the same.

Comment: Latest required drop ```combine:``` @IanMacDonald mentioned above:  ```var mostRecent = list.reduce(list[0], { $0.created.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.created.timeIntervalSince1970 ? $0 : $1 } )```
works brilliantly!

Answer (score 18):

Another approach is using Swift's `.max`, like this:

`dates.max(by: <)`

---

The following is my old answer. The above is updated in feb 2023.

```
let mostRecentDate = dates.max(by: {
   $0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < $1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
})
```

This is the most performant solution I've found.

Returns the sequence’s most recent date if the sequence is not empty; otherwise, nil.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest and best solution

Comment: This deserves to be the top answer

Comment: Clean and easy. It works on latest Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array, then find the first/last element. For example...

```
let objects: [Thing] = ... //Set the array
let mostResent = array.sorted { (firstThing, secondThing) -> Bool in
    firstThing.created.timeIntervalSince1970 > secondThing.created.timeIntervalSince1970
}.first
```

This will return the most resent Thing as an Optional (because there is no guarantee that the array is not empty. If you know that the array is not empty, then you can end that line with  `.first!`